# exact match in elasticSearch after incorporating hunspell filter

Tags: elasticsearch, hunspell

We have added the hunspell filter to our elastic search instance.  Nothing fancy...

```
{
"index" : {
    "analysis" : {
        "tokenizer" : {
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "pattern",
                "pattern" : ","
            }
        },            
          "filter": {
            "en_GB": {
              "type": "hunspell",
              "language": "en_GB"
            }
          },
        "analyzer" : {
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "comma"
            },
            "en_GB": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "en_GB"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
        }        
    }
}
}
```

Now though we seem to have lost the built in facility to do exact match queries using quotation marks.  So searching for "lace" will also do an equal score search for "lacy" for example. I understand this is kind of the point of including hunspell but I would like to be able to force exact matches by using quotes

I am doing boolean queries for this by the way.  Along the lines of (in java)

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "\"lace\"",
        "fields" : 
        ...
```

or (postman direct to 9200 ...

```
{
"query" : { 
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "\"lace\"",
    "fields" :
....
```

Is this possible ?  I'm guessing this might be something we would do in the tokaniser but I'm not quite sure where to start...?

Comment: let me get it first, you actually want to search on fields without matching it against the tokens provided by your analyzers, you want to bypass the hunspell effect on the query. am i right?

Comment: yes (I want to be able to bypass the hunspell effect as an option so that if someone wants to search on 'lace' without getting results for 'lacy' they can just add quotes, if they want the hunspell effect they will just search normally)

Comment: refer to my answer for bypassing hunspell effect, in my suggestion if you want to give the end user(someone sitting on desktop in backoffice) to bypass this effect i suggest you don't give them quotes as option to bypass. You can give them a radiobutton or something to bypass if they use it through some web/portal. Even if they use it through api take a boolean flag if they want to bypass the effect and then build query accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll take a look.  I was hoping for quotes as we have documentation on the site from previous hunspell guiding towards this behaviour but obviously we can change this if it's no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to handle this tokenizer level, but you can tweak configurations at mapping level to use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), you can keep a copy of the same field which will not be analyzed and later use this in query to support your usecase.

You can update your mappings like following

```
"mappings": {
        "desc": {
        "properties": {
           "labels": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "en_GB",
              "fields": {
              "raw": { 
              "type":  "keyword"
              }
            }
           }
        }
     }
    }
```

Furthur modify your query to search on raw field instead of analyzed field.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "labels.raw",
                    "query": "lace"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: Thanks,  Sorry I've had a bit of man flu so I haven't implemented/tested this yet I was just having a quick look before trying to do it properly tomorrow.  One quick question if you know the answer off hand (totally accept it's probably for me to look!) - does this have to be done at the field level (so I need to do this for each field in the mappings files as the examples seem to show or should I be able to modify the settings.json to do it at a global level ?